# sed - how to replace first word in line and preserve indents?

Tags: sed

For all lines that have `.to` I want to add `expect(` at the start.

For example for

```
blob.to 20
leave me
  Thing.to(30)
Other.to {all}
  leave me tooo
        far_in.to stuff
```

I would like to see:

```
expect(blob.to 20
leave me
  expect(Thing.to(30)
expect(Other.to {all}
  leave me tooo
        expect(far_in.to stuff
```

Currently I have:

```
sed -i '/.to/s/^[[:space]]*/expect(/' ../_spec_seded/"$file"
```

but am getting `sed: -e expression #1, char 28: unterminated`s' command`
from it

How do I resolve the error which I don't see yet and also 'preserve' spaces when doing this kind of substitution.

Bonus appreciation if you can *exclude* lines that have }.to instead of [any character except '}'].to

n.b. I deal with closing the parens separately.

p.s. unix site down right now.

Comment: [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) is not down for me.

Comment: Just change the `[[:space]]` to `[[:space:]]`.

Comment: hmm, dns showing U&L still down for me though other sites up.

Answer (score 4):

Your leading spaces *vanish* because you choose not to *preserve* those.  You could say:

```
sed '/.to/ s/^\([[:space:]]*\)/\1expect(/' filename
```

---

Alternatively, you could say:

```
sed '/\.to/ s/\(\S\)/expect(\1/' filename
```

For your input, it'd result in:

```
expect(blob.to 20
leave me
  expect(Thing.to(30)
expect(Other.to {all}
  leave me tooo
        expect(far_in.to stuff
```

---

> Bonus appreciation if you can exclude lines that have }.to instead of
>   [any character except '}'].to

If I understand it correct, you want to say:

```
sed '/[^}]\.to/ s/\(\S\)/expect(\1/' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\S\+\.to/expect(&/' file
```